# JavaFX directory file list

Tags: file-io, javafx

Has anybody know with what command I can get all files names in directory ?
I can`t find in tutorials.

pls, Help me

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that you can, in JavaFX scripts, directly use Java classes ? As a consequence, getting all file names in a directory in JavaFX works exactly like in Java (as JavaFX does not contains those kind of classes, focusing as it is on UI creation)j, that's to say by calling [`File#listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)